# Show that $m(A)=n(A)$ whenever $A\in\mathcal B$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying complete this problem from Bass' Real Analysis book:

> Let $\mathcal B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb{R}$, and suppose that $m,n$ are measures on $(\Bbb{R},\cal B)$ such that $m(a,b)=n(a,b)<\infty$ whenever $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Show that $m(A)=n(A)$ for all $A\in\cal B$.

I'm not really sure what the best way to proceed is. Obviously the result is true if $A$ is open, because then it's just a countable union of disjoint open intervals. However, I'm not sure how to classify what "every" element of $\cal B$ looks like; of course, it includes all closed intervals, and intervals of the form $[a,\infty)$, and so on... a proof by cases seems like it would make sense but I don't know how to be sure I've gotten *every* case.

Just to be clear, I'd prefer an insightful hint rather than somebody giving me the full solution.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. At that point in the book, have any extension theorems been covered?

Comment: Proof by cases for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra isn't worth trying.  The "easy" sets are easy to visualize, but many are hopelessly complex.  Too many cases overall.

Comment: It's worth mention that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the sigma algebra generated by the open subsets.  You have that the measures agree on the open subsets.  This should at least be a good indication of why it should be true.

Comment: One possible way to proceed would be to try to prove that the collection of subsets $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ for which $m(X) = n(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Bungo it's very early in the book, right after the section introducing measures, so no extension theorems. I'll try your second suggestion, that seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is Exercise 3.9 in Chatper 3 of Bass's [Real Analysis](http://bass.math.uconn.edu/rags010213.pdf). In Chapter 2 of his book (Proposition 2.8), it is shown that $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by the collection
$$
\mathcal{C}=\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$

What you need is the *monotone class theorem* in the very last section of Chapter 2.

**Hints**:

> - Show that $\mathcal{M}:=\{m(A)=n(A)\mid A\in\mathcal{B}\}$ is a monotone class.
> - [Added:] Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. Show that $m$ and $n$ agree on $\mathcal{A}$ also and thus $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{M}$.

---

[Added later:] It is worth noting that this is a common trick to deal with $\sigma$-algebras: instead of showing directly some statement (in this question $m(A)=n(A)$)  is true on a $\sigma$-algebra, one defines a collection of subsets where the statement holds. Then one shows that this collection coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra.

---

For the second bullete point of the hints, one can apply the similar idea. Instead of showing directly that $m$ and $n$ agree on the $\mathcal{A}$, one can show that
$\mathcal{M}$
 is an algebra. Then we must have $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{M}$ by the choice of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Great response, I do have one question though: the monotone class theorem holds in the case when $\cal C$ is an algebra, which it's not in our case. So should I be letting $\cal A$ denote the algebra generated by $\cal C$ here, so $\sigma(\cal A)= B$, and then show that $\cal A\subset M$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `:-)`

Comment: @AlexMathers It might be slightly easier to work with half-open intervals, $\mathcal H = \{(a,b] : a,b \in [-\infty, \infty]\}$. The reason this set is easier to work with is that the algebra generated by $\mathcal H$ is simply the collection of finite unions of elements of $\mathcal H$, whereas the algebra generated by $\mathcal C$ contains open intervals, closed intervals, half-open intervals, etc. It is not hard to see that $m$ and $n$ must agree on $\mathcal H$, and that $\sigma(\mathcal H) = \mathcal B$.

Comment: @Bungo this may be a good suggestion because I'm having a hard time showing $\cal A\subset M$. I'll update if I make any progress

Comment: @AlexMathers: In fact, showing $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{M}$ could be easy if one does not do it in a "direct" way.

Comment: @Jack in your edit, is $\cal A_0$ deliberately the same as $\cal M$? It seems ultimately the approach then is to just let $\mathcal A_0=\{A\in\mathcal B:m(A)=n(A)\}$, then show that $\cal A_0$ is both an algebra and a monotone class, so that it is a $\sigma$-algebra by the monotone class theorem.

Comment: @AlexMathers: Yes! $\mathcal{A}_0$ is redundant. All one needs there is showing that $\mathcal{M}$ is an algebra. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll stop bombarding you with questions now

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to show something about every Borel subset by fixing $A\in\mathcal{B}$ because like you noted, an arbitrary Borel set might be quite complicated and we can't just write it down as some convenient union. Instead, it is often more fruitful to consider the collection with the desired property and show that it contains the Borel sets, for which it is sufficient to show that such a collection contains the open sets and is a $\sigma$-algebra (then it must contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open sets). So in this case, fix $\mathcal{A}=\{A\subset\mathbb{R}\mid m(A)=n(A)\}$ and try to show that such a set is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the open sets. As Jack noted, the monotone class theorem is often useful when you're trying to prove a collection is a $\sigma$-algebra, and you should think about using it here.